# Send mail if date in cell is 2 years older than the current date

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a macro which lists the name, path, Creation date, modification date of all the files and subfolders in an excel worksheet, this macro is working absolutely fine.

However now I want to create a macro which can check the entire list of files and folders and if the Date creation date (Column F ) of any listed files/folders is greater than 2 years from the current date, it should send an automated mail giving the name of the file, its path and the creation and modification information (basically copy all the information of that particular row) to me.

Please find below the code in which I am getting the error (Run time Error) on 
this line :

```
Sub send_files()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim FileCell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim sDate As String

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
sDate = Date

For Each cell In sh.Columns("F").Cells
    Days = DateDiff("yyyy", Cells.Value, sDate)
    If Days > 2 Then
                Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
            .to = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Testfile"
            .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
            .send

        End With
    End If
Next cell

Set OutApp = Nothing
With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

The error occurs on:

```
Days = DateDiff("yyyy", Cells.Value, sDate)
```

Can anyone assist with this error?

Answer (score 4):

Try changing

```
Days = DateDiff("yyyy", Cells.Value, sDate)
```

to

```
Days = DateDiff("yyyy", cell.Value, sDate)
```

Comment: Now it gives error Runtime error 13 : Type mismatch

Comment: Looking at your code, you're reading **Every** cell in column F! You might want to check that the cell contains a date before you attempt to `DateDiff` it.

Comment: atleast it should give result for the cells which are filled.

Comment: Does the first cell contain a header? If so, it'll error there and stop. If not, you're right, it should work its way down until it does error. You could use error handling but that would be highly inefficient. Better to set your range up correctly in the first place and ignore empty cells if they can exist in the range.

Comment: I have modified the range but still its giving error:

Comment: bottomA = sh.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row: x = 2
    
  For Each cell In sh.Range("F1:F" & bottomA)
  Days = DateDiff("yyyy", cell.Value, sDate)
  If Days > 2 Then

Comment: Does cell F1 on sheet `Sheet1` contain a date. Is it stored as a date or text? Don't forget the `IsDate` function could be used here to check within the loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139522/discussion-between-astha-and-clr).